# Create, as a regular user, a tar with files owned by root

Tags: permissions, tar, root, packaging, ownership

I want to build a tar file as **regular (non-root) user** with some prepared binaries and configuration files like this;

```
etc/binaries.conf
usr/bin/binary1
usr/bin/binary2
```

that are mean to be extracted into the file system under the `/` directory.

Like a traditional software package .deb, .rpm etc but I need to be "package manager independent". So probably I will just have a .tar file (maybe some gzip, bzip, lzip should be added to the mix but that's outside).

**PROBLEM / QUESTION**

My problem here is that I **don't** want to build this tar as the **root** user, and I want to know if there is a way to build this tar as a **regular (non-root) user** and then, when the .tar file is distributed to the machines and the real `root` user extract those binaries, they will be installed as files owned by the **root** user or the user who extract the binaries ?

**EXAMPLE**

Because right now, when I just create the .tar file as a **regular (non-root) user** with

```
$ tar cf dist.tar dist/
```

And then extract the .tar as **root** user with

```
# tar xf dist.tar -C /
```

I see the binaries and the config file with the regular user as owner, not the root user.

```
$ ls -la /usr/bin/binary1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 30232 jun  20 19:06 /usr/bin/binary1
```

And I wan to have

```
$ ls -la /usr/bin/binary1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 30232 jun  20 19:06 /usr/bin/binary1
```

Just to clarify, this hand made packaging is very specific for some task in a closed infrastructure, so right now, using .deb, .rpm or any other more sophisticated packaging system is not an option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **extraction** is what determines the ownership, not the **creation** of the archive.  You can see that by looking at the archive's table of contents, e.,g.,

```
tar tvf dist.tar
```

If creating the file as regular user

```
tar --owner 0 --group 0 dist.tar dist
```

do the magic

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer @Thomas Dickey, but when I do that the files are listed with the information of the regular (non-root) user, and I want to have the root user as owner, even if do the extract process (as root) with `# tar xvf dist.tar` the ownership of the regular user is preserved

Comment: tar shows the ownership of the files that you archived - your question didn't say that you created them as yourself.  If you happen to use GNU tar, you could use the `--owner` and `--group` options to pretend that was not the case.

Comment: Ok, clarified. the --owner and --group did the trick thank you

Comment: Yes, and it is a "try" thing (if the UID/GID doesn't exist, etc) and per the man page it is the default action when the root user is extracting... see the `--same-owner` option

Comment: Yes, you could add the owners when extracting as root, which is probably good practice anyway. But for distribution, you should really consider creating the archive with root ownerships. See http://billauer.co.il/blog/2020/11/tar-create-owner-group/